# How to handle file upload with jquery validation

Tags: jquery, file, file-upload, validation

I am using the jquery validation plugin located here:

http://bassistance.de/2011/05/14/release-validation-plugin-1-8-1/

And I'm trying to find out if I can use jQuery's ajax somehow to work with file uploads because I have a form with a few inputs and text areas and a file upload file along with the form. What I'm wanting to do with the file upload is have it upload to a certain directory in my hosting.

Comment: What does validation have to do with the target directory for the upload?

Comment: I'm just saying I'm a little confused on how to handle this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing away with the file upload this is solved.